# CAAnimation hides half of view

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, calayer, caanimation

I'm making a card game, where I need the cards to "flip over". To be first face down and then flip around, so the face is up. I've made a nice animation to do it and it works nicely, except that half of the view is hidden behind the layer behind during the animation (see screenshot).

When the animation is done, the card view stacks nice on top of the other views.

**Any hints on why half of the view is hidden during the animation?**

**Screenshot:**
[image: Screenshot 1]

**Code:**

```
- (void)setFaceDirection:(BOOL)up{
    if(up && !self.faceUp){
        self.faceUp = up;
        [self flip:@"in"];
    }else if(!up && self.faceUp){
        self.faceUp = up;
        [self flip:@"out"];
    }
}

- (void)flip:(NSString *)direction{
    NSLog(@"flip");
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(firstFlip) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.2 target:self selector:@selector(secondFlip) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)firstFlip{
    [CATransaction begin];
    CAAnimation* anim1 = [self createAnimDirection:@"in"];
    [CATransaction commit];

    //add perspective
    CATransform3D mt = CATransform3DIdentity;
    mt.m34 = 1.0/1000;
    mt = CATransform3DTranslate(mt, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.01f);

    CALayer* lr = [self layer];
    lr.transform = mt;

    NSPoint ap = {0.5,0.0}; // Begin from OS X Mountain Lion ancorPoint by default at 0,0;
    lr.anchorPoint = ap;

    // animation delegate to this class to handle message on its completion
    anim1.delegate = self; 

    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), self.frame.origin.y);
    // lr.position = center;  

    [CATransaction begin];
    [lr addAnimation:anim1 forKey:@"flip"];
    [CATransaction commit];
}

- (void)secondFlip{
    [CATransaction begin];
    CAAnimation* anim1 = [self createAnimDirection:@"out"];
    [CATransaction commit];

    //add perspective
    CATransform3D mt = CATransform3DIdentity;
    mt.m34 = 1.0/1000;
    mt = CATransform3DTranslate(mt, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.01f);

    CALayer* lr = [self layer];
    lr.transform = mt;

    NSPoint ap = {0.5,0}; // Begin from OS X Mountain Lion ancorPoint by default at 0,0;
    lr.anchorPoint = ap;

    // animation delegate to this class to handle message on its completion
    anim1.delegate = self; 

    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), self.frame.origin.y);
    lr.position = center;  

    [CATransaction begin];
    [lr addAnimation:anim1 forKey:@"flip"];
    [CATransaction commit];
}

- (CAAnimation*) createAnimDirection:(NSString *) direction
{
    double from = 0.0;
    double to = M_PI/2;
    if ([direction isEqualToString:@"in"]){
        [self setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"Card_Background"]];
    }else{
        from = -M_PI/2;
        to = 0.0;
        [self setImage:self.faceImage];
    }

    NSString* sRotation;
    sRotation = @"transform.rotation.y";
    CABasicAnimation* ba = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:sRotation];
    ba.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:from];
    ba.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:to];

    CAAnimationGroup *animationGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    animationGroup.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:ba, nil];
     animationGroup.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    animationGroup.duration = 1.2;
    animationGroup.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animationGroup.removedOnCompletion = NO;

    return animationGroup;
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag{
    if(flag){
        if (self.faceUp){
            [self setImage:self.faceImage];
        }else{
            [self setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"Card_Background"]];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set the `zIndex` of the cards?

Comment: Have you looked at adding a `z`translation of half of the card width?

Comment: No. I'm still very noob'ish when it comes to CAAnimations. @DavidRönnqvist How do I set the z-index of the cards? Why is it only half the card that is hidden? What is the z-translation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up messing around with the xIndex of the cards, so now it works.

I've changed the code so much that I can't post it here though.